# imagemagick cropping image creates jagged edges or saw-tooth shapes

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

[image]

The above pic (looks like zoomed one ) is from first level conversion from 1.Ai file 1_cropped.AI file what I get after cropping. I don't do resize during cropping it gets automatically resized.
I am trying crop an image, Seems without +repage imagemagick unable to crop. The problem is a simple crop created the jagged lines as you can see from the snapshot taken from a portion of image.
How to remove this. Some where in SOF post I found a recommendation to use "Gaussian blur" but didn't find a proper command to do the same. Many thanks! I am doing just the crop and no resizing.

Original : Due to copyright can't show the entire image. But below is one section:
[image]

Looking into : http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/antialiasing/ now but unable to smoothe the 'stair case' or 'jaggies' so far.

UPDATE from the comments:
Yes the input is AI and output is almost all format AI/SVG/PNG/GIF/JPEG/BMP. So for smaller resolution files such as png/GIF I don't get that jagged shapes I I tried turning on anti-aliasing , blurring and guassian-bluring but no luck.  I think the repaging zooms the image which I don't need, is it possible to set the canvas somehow so the original resolution is kept intact when converting from AI to AI? Yes initially I convert AI to AI after cropping and than feed the converted AI for further processing. The stair-stepping appears from first level AI to AI file conversion itself.

Comment: Please show your original image before cropping and not zoomed

Comment: Yes Added one section now although it looked like zoomed but it's the actual image I got after cropping.  I just do crop and not resize. My intention is to keep the original one and don't resize but due to +repage I think this happens. I am yet to find crop without +repage.

Comment: The stair stepping is due to antialiasing when drawing the line. When you zoom, you will see the shading to go from black to white in graduations. You will never avoid that when zooming.  The original looks fine and does not have significant stair-stepping. I think your only possibility might be raster to vector conversion. What kind of input do you have where you think this is happening. Are you starting with a vector format such as AI, or PNG or SVG? If so, the rasterization will do what you see. If you turn off antialiasing, then you will see bigger blocks in the steps

Comment: Yes you are right the input is AI and output is almost all format PNG/GIG/JPEG/BMP.